# how to compare 2 records on basis of nearest time in sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

there are two table 
first one having scheduled time

```
BusDepartureStation   ArrivalStation  DepartureTime
A                         B             10:00
A                         B             13:00
C                         D             18:00
C                         D             22:00
```

second table having actual time

```
BusDepartureStation   ArrivalStation  DepartureTime
A                         B             10:15
A                         B             13:30
c                         D             18:10
C                         D             22:00
```

Comment: Can you give what is your expected output? I cant understand what actually you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    s.BusDepartureStation, s.BusArrivalStation, s.DepartureTime,
    dateadd(
        mi,
        min(case
            when d.DepartureTime >= s.DepartureTime
            then datediff(mi, s.DepartureTime, d.DepartureTime), s.DepartureTime)
            else null
        end),
        s.DepartureTime
    ) as NextNearestDepartureTime
from Scheduled s inner join Departed d
    on      d.BusDepartureStation = s.BusDepartureStation
        and d.ArrivalStation = s.ArrivalStation
group by
    s.BusDepartureStation, s.BusArrivalStation, s.DepartureTime
```

For this I'm assuming that your departures are never early and that the earlier scheduled departure always leaves before the subsequent bus. And if my assumption about SQL Server is incorrect you should be able to adjust the time difference logic to use MySQL functions instead.